# Reload the content of JSP page within GWT

Tags: jsp, gwt, refresh, reload

I have an jsp, which is embedded in our GWT application. The jsp give me 32 result of a select statement from the DB. I want to pass limit and offset parameters, to get only 10 results per page. Then i need paging functionality. For the paging i need to pass another parameters and to refresh only the jsp and not the entire view. What can be used to enable the paging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with the GWT History....for that i manipulate url part after `#`, for example `http://localhost:8080/client/index.html#token?param1=1&param2=2` can be changed to `http://localhost:8080/client/index.html#token?param1=2&param2=3` and then only the jsp will be reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RequestBuilder](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html) to make arbitrary http requests.  If your jsp file is also producing the html host page for your gwt code, you will have to refactor - you cannot reload the host page without reloading the entire view.